# Provide dependencies from app module in hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I've realized that I can provide dependencies from my `:app` module to other modules that depends on them but the same technique doesn't work for other modules.

In short:

`:app` module depends on `:B` module and can provide dependencies to `:B` module

`:C` module depends on `:B` but CAN'T provide dependencies to `:B` module.

Why is that? Is `:app` module special?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading the docs I realized this is because the module that contains the `HiltAndroidApp` generates all the hilt code.

In my case, the `:app` module wasn't dependent on `:C` module, therefore it didn't generate the hilt code because `:app` couldn't access it.

Solution, add `:C` module to your app module and `:B` module will work!

Quoting it from here -> https://dagger.dev/hilt/application

> All apps using Hilt must contain an Application class annotated with
> @HiltAndroidApp. @HiltAndroidApp kicks off the code generation of the
> Hilt components and also generates a base class for your application
> that uses those generated components. **Because the code generation
> needs access to all of your modules, the target that compiles your
> Application class also needs to have all of your Dagger modules in its
> transitive dependencies.**